# i got some error when i write cell using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

i want to write function factors in excel file using openpyxl.
Even though there is a file, the contents of the file are not written and if works in console, but it causes this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

```py
wb = openpyxl.Workbook("sample.xlsx")
sheet = wb.active


def determinehamsu(t,n,bid_t,w,h,k):

    encode = LabelEncoder()
    rank = determineRank(t,n,bid_t,w,h,k)
    x = 1

    if bid_t <= 6010:
        for bid_t in range(bid_t, 6010,10):
            rank = determineRank(t,n,bid_t,w,h,k)
            print(rank)
            print(bid_t)
            sheet.append([t,n,bid_t,w,h,k])
            wb.save("sample.xlsx")
    elif bid_t > 6010:
        for bid_t in range(bid_t,0,-10):
            rank = determineRank(t,n,bid_t,w,h,k)
            print(rank)
            print(bid_t)
            sheet.append([t,n,bid_t,w,h,k])
            wb.save("sample.xlsx")
```

this is code what i executed. determineRank function is works very well in my computer.
What I want to do is to save the factors of the function in the sample.xlsx file. How do i fix that function to work?

Comment: Are you sure that you have a sheet in your Excel file? If not you should create one. BTW, this is a documentation related questions, consider checking : https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html

Comment: I strongly recommend reading this article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.